# Placing text and equations inside a box

Tags: formatting, framed

I have a paragraph that contains text, inline equations and centred equations, and I'd like to put the whole thing in a box that's centred horizontally in the page. It's a key paragraph, so I wanted to box it so that it stands out. I just want a simple box: black outline, white fill, no curved corners.

I had a look at questions with similar titles, but couldn't find anything that both worked and suited my needs. If it helps, see below for the particular paragraph I want to put in a box:

```
\documentclass[12pt article]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

    Let $a(b) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} hi & \mbox{if } t^5 \mbox{ reduced} \\ t & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$, $xyz = \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} GH & \mbox{if } tr^{\pi} \mbox{ secluded} \\ x& \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$, $s = \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} up^{-5} & \mbox{if } t^55 \mbox{ reduced} \\ lo & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$. \\ \\

    Define the magician $M_n$ recursively, where $M_1 = \bigstar$ and 

    \begin{center} $  \begin{array}{r} M_{3} =   tr(Md) \\ M_{hat} =   norbert(2304) \\ Mtri =   solution \end{array} $ \end{center}

    where $z$ is the smallest integer such that $z \notin \{ 0 \}$. Terminate the magician at $M_{3}$ where $3$ is such that $M_{3}, ... , M_{3}$ have all already appeared in $M_1, ... , M_{t},$ i.e.

    \begin{center}

    $ Mtr = g, \underbrace{hi, hello, good day}_{\mbox{cousins}}, \underbrace{1,2,3,4,4,5}_{\mbox{enemies of first cousin of } g} , ... \ , M_{3}, M_{3}, M_{3} $

    \end{center}

    where $i$ is smallest such that $rt \neq z$.

\end{document}
```

Thanks! I wasn't sure what tags to use - I'd welcome any changes.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering from the content - yes, this is part of a breakthrough paper in mathematics that will change the way we view everything

Comment: It already did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not need a pagebreak inside the box, simply use a tabular, otherwise look at the package `framed`

```
\documentclass[12pt article]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\linewidth}|}\hline % or any other width
\rule{0pt}{5ex}% for more vertical space
    Let $a(b) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} hi & \mbox{if } t^5 \mbox{ reduced} \\ t & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$, $xyz = \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} GH & \mbox{if } tr^{\pi} \mbox{ secluded} \\ x& \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$, $s = \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} up^{-5} & \mbox{if } t^55 \mbox{ reduced} \\ lo & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$. \\ \\

    Define the magician $M_n$ recursively, where $M_1 = \bigstar$ and 

    \begin{center} $  \begin{array}{r} M_{3} =   tr(Md) \\ M_{hat} =   norbert(2304) \\ Mtri =   solution \end{array} $ \end{center}

    where $z$ is the smallest integer such that $z \notin \{ 0 \}$. Terminate the magician at $M_{3}$ where $3$ is such that $M_{3}, ... , M_{3}$ have all already appeared in $M_1, ... , M_{t},$ i.e.

    \begin{center}
    $ Mtr = g, \underbrace{hi, hello, good day}_{\mbox{cousins}}, \underbrace{1,2,3,4,4,5}_{\mbox{enemies of first cousin of } g} , ... \ , M_{3}, M_{3}, M_{3} $
    \end{center}

    where $i$ is smallest such that $rt \neq z$.\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Is there any way to increase the (/create a) gap between the top line and the first line of text?

Comment: Put before "Let" at the beginning of the first line `\rule{0pt}{5ex}`. Could also be done with the tabular column specification, but then it may be a problem when another box has no array in the first line.

Comment: see my edited code

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [the `mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed) to define a custom environment.
This has the advantages that you get all the flexibility inherent with `tikz` (if you use the `framemethod=tikz` option) and will also work across page boundaries.

### Note:

- I have taken the liberty to reformat the equations (but feel free to adjust as you desire).

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt article]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,xcolor=true]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[%
    leftmargin=0.5cm,
    backgroundcolor=yellow!10,%
    roundcorner=5pt,%
    tikzsetting={draw=red, line width=2.0pt}%
    ]{SpecialText}%
    

\newcommand*{\Format}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$xyz$}][r]{$#1$}}%
\newcommand*{\PhantomLet}{\mbox{\hphantom{Let }}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{SpecialText}
Let $\Format{a(b)} = \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} hi & \mbox{if } t^5 \mbox{ reduced} \\ t & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$,

\smallskip
\PhantomLet $\Format{xyz} = \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} GH & \mbox{if } tr^{\pi} \mbox{ secluded} \\ x& \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$,

\smallskip
\PhantomLet $\Format{s} = \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} up^{-5} & \mbox{if } t^55 \mbox{ reduced} \\ lo & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$. \\ \\

Define the magician $M_n$ recursively, where $M_1 = \bigstar$ and 
%
\begin{align*}
    M_{3}   &=   tr(Md) \\ 
    M_{hat} &=   norbert(2304) \\ 
    Mtri    &=   solution
\end{align*}
%
where $z$ is the smallest integer such that $z \notin \{ 0 \}$. Terminate the magician at $M_{3}$ where $3$ is such that $M_{3}, ... , M_{3}$ have all already appeared in $M_1, ... , M_{t},$ i.e.
%
\[
Mtr = g, \underbrace{hi, hello, good day}_{\mbox{cousins}}, \underbrace{1,2,3,4,4,5}_{\mbox{enemies of first cousin of } g} , ... \ , M_{3}, M_{3}, M_{3}
\]
%
where $i$ is smallest such that $rt \neq z$.
\end{SpecialText}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you pair down this to a minimum working example? Preferably one where there is no need to define newcommands.

Comment: @MichaelLevy: Not sure what the purpose of not defining `\newcommand`s would be -- you can of course use the definition of the \`newcommand`s directly in the text body. I suggest you post a new question explaining what you are trying to achive. Also, `mdframed` hasn't been updated in a long time, so would recommend using the `tcolorbox` package instead -- that has a lot more flexability.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
Let
\begin{align*}
a(b) &= 
  \left\{ \begin{array}{@{}c l} 
    hi & \text{if $t^5$ reduced} \\ 
    t  & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right. 
&
xyz &= 
  \left\{ \begin{array}{@{}c l} 
    GH & \text{if $tr^{\pi}$ secluded} \\ 
    x  & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right. 
\\
s &=
  \left\{ \begin{array}{@{}c l}
    up^{-5} & \text{if $t^{55}$ reduced} \\ 
    lo      & \text{otherwise} 
  \end{array} \right.
\end{align*}

Define the magician $M_n$ recursively, where $M_1 = \bigstar$ and 
\begin{align*}
  M_{3}   &= \textit{tr}(Md) \\
  M_{hat} &= \textit{norbert}(2304) \\ 
  Mtri    &= \textit{solution}
\end{align*}
where $z$ is the smallest integer such that $z \notin \{ 0 \}$. Terminate the magician at 
$M_{3}$ where $3$ is such that $M_{3},\dots, M_{3}$ have all already appeared in $M_1, 
\dots, M_{t}$, i.e.,
\[
Mtr = g, 
\underbrace{\text{hi, hello, good day}}_{\text{cousins}}, 
\underbrace{1,2,3,4,4,5}_{\text{enemies of first cousin of $g$}},
\dots , M_{3}, M_{3}, M_{3} 
\]
where $i$ is smallest such that $rt \neq z$.
\end{minipage}}% end of \fbox
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Please, look carefully at the code, as yours shows many LaTeX weaknesses, particularly in the use of `\mbox` and of "multiletter identifiers".

The trick is to `\fbox` a `minipage`. There are other methods.

Comment: Thanks. This is first time I've used LaTeX, still learning as a I go

Comment: @Matt: If you want the text contained with the `minipage` to "line up" with the margins of the surrounding text, use `\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}...\end{minipage}}}` in egreg's answer. `\fbox` adds some space (`2\fboxsep`) and rules (`2\fboxrule`) on the sides of the box, which causes some LaTeX warnings (Overfull `\hbox` warnings). Therefore, putting the entire thing in a `\makebox[\textwidth]{..}` without an indent (via `\noindent`) removes these warnings. Regardless, `minipage`s are not breakable across page boundaries.